# Прямой доступ к устройству linux? Как это устроено в seastar

Tags: c++, linux, unix, dma

На днях узнал про необычный фреймворк - seastar. Он заинтересовал меня тем, что (по словам разработчиков) реализует взаимодействие с диском и сокетами в обход posix api. К примеру реализует dma чтение. Погуглив я ничего не нашел по этой теме, хотел бы узнать, каким образом возможно получить прямой доступ к устройству в linux? Как во фреймворке может быть реализована кернел спейс функциональность?

Comment: «в обход posix api» — где об этом сказано? В документации подобного не вижу

Comment: @andreymal, Seastar provides a simple networking API, backed by two TCP/IP stacks: the POSIX stack, utilizing the kernel's BSD socket APIs, and the native stack, implement fully within seastar and able to drive network cards directly. The native stack supports zero-copy on both transmit and receive, and is implemented using seastar's high performance, lockless sharded design. The network stack can be selected with the --network-stack command-line parameter.

https://docs.seastar.io/master/group__networking-module.html

Comment: Поглядите на реализацию этих posix API.

Comment: Они [пишут](https://seastar.io/networking/), что через [DPDK](https://habr.com/ru/company/selectel/blog/313150/)

Comment: [Userspace I/O](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/driver-api/uio-howto.html) в Linux есть с незапамятных времён. Для того, чтобы писать в сетевую карту напрямую, нужно отмапить её адресное пространство PCI в адресное пространство процесса и настроить коллбеки для обработки прерываний. Для того, чтобы это работало, нужно знать назначение регистров PCI и прерываний карты. Уверен, что Seastar работает с очень ограниченным набором карт, для которых они знают регистры и прерывания.

Comment: @PakUula, причём тут это? Почитайте про DPDK,

Comment: @0andriy именно что почитал. Упоминают vfio_pci, igb_uio или uio_pci_generic. Это всё технологии прямого доступа к PCI устройству за счёт отмапливания страниц ввода-вывода карты и управляющих регистров в адресное пространство процесса. DPDK - это надстройка над Userspace I/O. ТС спросил "прямой доступ к устройству в linux" - именно на этот вопрос я ответил: через Userspace I/O.